# Bijective Single Type Collection

Tags: java, dictionary, bijection

Are there any bijective data structures that use only one type such that if `a -> b` then `b -> a` where a and b are of the same type? I have looked at `BiMap` of Guava and `BidiMap` of Apache Commons but both require getting the inverse of the map to check reverse mappings whereas I would like it not to matter. If there is not one in an existing collection, would a simple class like this do the trick or is there any problem with this:

```
public class BiHashMap<T> extends HashMap<T, T> {

    @Override
    public T put(T key1, T key2) {
        T removed = remove(key1);
        remove(key2);
        super.put(key1, key2);
        super.put(key2, key1);
        return removed;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(Object key) {
        T mapped = super.remove(key);
        super.remove(mapped);
        return mapped;
    }

}
```

Comment: Uh, what is supposed to happen if you .put(k1, k2) then .put(k2, k3)?

Comment: k1 should have its mapping removed and then `k2 -> k3` and `k3 -> k2`. Which my example wont do. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Hm - that's *exactly* what your example would do, as far as I can see. I guess the crucial point is the expected semantics of the map. E.g. when you `put(1,2)`, then the `keySet` will be `{1,2}`, and there can no longer be duplicate *values*. This may be obvious according to your goal, but might be confusing for someone who only knows this map as a `Map`, and not as a `BiHashMap`....

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks for the feedback. I had made the changes to fix the point raised by fge already in the example. Yes the implementation doesn't quite follow the rules of a Map but it can be used where ever a map would be used and was easier to use the pre-existing HashMap as the base.

Comment: I see. One of the only alternatives that I could think of would be an own implementation of Map (maybe extending AbstractMap) that internally stores *two* maps, a "forward" and a "backward" map, but have not thoroughly thought about this yet, and can imagine that this would bring no real benefit (despite the higher implementation effort)